# How to send 500 request per second in 100 loop count using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to test 500 request per second in a loop count of 100 (Totally 50,000 request) using Jmeter.
I have to send 500 each sec irrespective of me getting a response, i.e.even if my previous 500 requests fails, I have to send my next 500 requests.

Currently I have used a constant timer of 1 second and set the Thread count to 500 and Loop count to 100 with a Ramp up period of 1.

And I don't think I'm getting the desired results correctly.

So what settings I must use to achieve the desired result.[image: Jmeter Thread group img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean:

1. send 500 requests
2. wait 1 second
3. send another 500 requests
4. wait 1 second
5. repeat steps 1-2 98 more times

you need to amend your test plan configuration to include [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) with `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` set to `500` and replace the Constant Timer with the [Flow Control Action sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)

Comment: Yeah, This is our needed use case. Can you also state which option to choose in Flow Control Action Sampler among "Start next thread group" and "Go to next Iteration of current loop" . (I need to send 500 requests irrespective of the response I get)

Comment: "Pause" for "1000" milliseconds

Comment: After obtaining the result in csv format, I have plotted the time difference between 400 rows (used thread count as 400 and loop count as 125). I found that the time difference between two request is more than 2 sec (1 sec for req + 1 sec for pause time). I don't know how to calculate or put into account for the timing thing happening here. Link to the obtained csv: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1POhhko5_2PlvnmEhHlJVuD9EGxraYdSp/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=118374170451190587355&rtpof=true&sd=true
So now my question is does jmeter wait more than a sec to send next 400 requests?

Comment: 1. It's another separate question. 2. JMeter waits for response from the previous request before starting the next one. 3. Your application needs to be able to process 500 requests per second. If you want to try to keep the load at "500 requests per second" rate you can consider [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) combination (you may need more than 500 users for this)